Pylance in vsCode not activated
So I have a new installation of VSCode 1.91.1 in Win10, and installed Python and Pylance, but it's not highlighting thing like variables.
I checked my settings.json and all it has is this!

{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark"
}

I find it quite odd that they expect me to google what should be in there and paste it in?! Am I missing something here?

settings.json just has modified settings, if you want to open their Settings panel, go to File > Preferences > Settings then search for your desired settings there

This question is similar to: Visual Studio Code syntax highlighting not working. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

So I tried reinstalling all the plugins, didn't work. Eventually I noticed a message came up in VS about something missing. I clicked ignore, and shortly after that, it did work. Thought it was insignificant at the time but I think it was related to this.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
